# VC++ and MFC Applications

Tags: mfc

Is there any way to integrate the codes written in CRichEditView and CScrollView in VC++, to run as a single application.....

Comment: Do you want a CRichEditView where you can draw extra stuff yourself or what is your goal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why you would want to do this, CRichEditView is the basis of Windows Wordpad application after all.

Look here for more information and links to the source code:

[Link to MSDN Wordpad page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y8h3tk%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion, i m new to this site, i dont know how exactly i have to accept the answers suggested. I m just replying through my openid.